# Wordpress slugs and 404 handling takes preference over folders in site root?

Tags: customization, permalinks, slug, options, htaccess

I have wordpress installed and permalink structure set to /%postname%/

In addition to WordPress folders, I also have a public_html/beta folder where I wanted to copy the same site and test some unreleased features.

However, whenever I navigate to http://mysite.com/beta , I get the WordPress message saying "Sorry, but you're looking for something that isn't there".

So the question is how do I make the folder take higher priority/preference than the wordpress slugs? :/

Thanks!

Edit: here's the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://mysite.com/beta/` *(with a trailing slash?)*  Also please update your question and include the contents of the `/public_html/.htaccess` file, and the contents of the `/public_html/beta/.htaccess` file if one exists.

Comment: @Mike, yes I did try that too, that was the first thing I tried. I switched the permalink structure to /%category%/%postname%/, it doesn't help either.

Comment: Okay, here's the thing. My /beta/ folder was password-protected. Removing the protection makes it work. I need the password protection, so this is really weird :/

Comment: Remove the password protection and use the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) which will force people to have a user account in order to access your beta site.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Please add your last comment as an answer. I'll upvote it then and we have one unanswered question less.

Answer (score 1):

For beta testing use either a separate domain or at least a subdomain in another directory than your live site.

If you absolutely have to use the current setup install a plugin that offers password protection like [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) or change the .htaccess rules to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# exclude /beta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/beta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

… and create a separate .htaccess for the beta site.